# And of number and its Two's complement

Tags: binary, numbers, twos-complement

Is there any semantic meaning when doing an `and` operation of a number and its two's complement?

for example:

```
int x = 31;
int result = x & (-x)
```

Does result hold any semantic meaning?

Answer (score 0):

The result will have one bit set, which is the least-significant set bit in `x`. Put another way, the result indicates how "round" `x` is in terms of powers of 2: 1 for odd numbers, 2 for multiples of 2, 4 for multiples of 4, etc.

This is because `-x` is equal to `~x + 1`. `x & ~x` is 0, of course, but by adding 1 to `~x` all of the lowest-order 1s in `~x` will become 0s, and the lowest-order 0 in `~x` will become a 1, and this will be the only bit that `x` and `~x + 1` have in common.